# ListView in AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am using a ListView in an AlertDialog to display a list of items. When the user clicks on one of the items, I want the dialog to close. I would not have any action buttons on the dialog. Any ideas on how I would accomplish this?

Comment: You can also see this sample of alert dialog with listview go here [for demo example](http://goo.gl/W3a4h)

Answer (score 92):

You should be able to do something like:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
         // Do something with the selection
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

This [page](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) has some other examples of different types of Dialogs.

Comment: just put dismiss() in the public void onClick() function will dismiss the dialog for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a layout when popping an alert dialog.. It is easier to style it that way imo.
For list in alert dialog you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12692365/634337)

Answer (score 0):

Used below code to display custom list in AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    DialogActivity.this);
            builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Name:-");
            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    DialogActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
            arrayAdapter.add("Hardik");
            arrayAdapter.add("Archit");
            arrayAdapter.add("Jignesh");
            arrayAdapter.add("Umang");
            arrayAdapter.add("Gatti");
            builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                            AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    DialogActivity.this);
                            builderInner.setMessage(strName);
                            builderInner.setTitle("Your Selected Item is");
                            builderInner.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                            builderInner.show();
                        }
                    });
            builderSingle.create();
            builderSingle.show();
```