# Dialog which include items

Tags: android

i want to create a dialog which when popup will show items. but the problem is that when i am popping my dialog it is showing only the title and a blank space i am not getting my items in my dialog.here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

  final String list[]={"r","g","b"};

  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(myAct.this);

  alert.setTitle("dialog with list");

  alert.setItems(list,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+list[which],1000).show()
    }
  });
  alert.show();
```

Comment: check this: [ListView in AlertDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397106/listview-in-alertdialog)

Comment: yes i have checked this and also follow this but not getting output which i want. i still got the blank dialog box with just only title and a blank white space.

Comment: http://deadmango.com/index.php/archives/1025

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Did you refer to this?

If so, can you try this

```
final String[] list={"r","g","b"};
```

instead of

```
final String list[]={"r","g","b"};
```

Comment: then why dont you create a listview inside the dialog and populate it? Do you necessarily only want to use the default capability?

Comment: yes i have done with that and its working for me but why the default method setItems() is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding items in `CharSequence[]`. Refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) for more details.

Comment: yes i am also using the same thing but unfortunately items is being 

not added in my dialog.it is showing dialog only with title and some 

blank space.

Comment: Please go thru the doc. It will definitely solve your problem. Use alert.create() instead of alert.show();

Comment: i have read the docs and also following. but every time i am getting the same output.and alert.create() will create the dialog but for showing the dialog i have to call show() method.