# android developer alert dialog + listview function

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I wrote some code which implements the listView inside alertDialog. now when i want to implement some function on the listview I didnt succeed doing it. here is the code to he alertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select Name");
ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
String[] stringArray = new String[] {"red" , "green" , "blue"};
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
builder.setView(modeList);
final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

how can i implement a function on a clicked item?

Comment: You have to create your own custom adapter and add listener for decided item in row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [build in implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397143/799799) of list in alert dialog. It depends on use case. If you want to use this dialog just for picking value from the list (without custom list item UI) - it is good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this code : it shows an alertDialog with a listView containing your values :

```
CharSequence[]  stringArray =  {"red" , "green" , "blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select Name");
builder.setItems(stringArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
         // Do something with the selection
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```