# How to unlock a feature when user shares app?

Tags: android

I want to hide the dark theme mode of one of my app behind "a share app to unlock feature". When the user shares the app to one of friend or through social media, he gets the dark theme, how can I accomplish this in android?

Comment: You can't check that is user really shared the app. Nevertheless if you use back-end web service and check any friend of the user registered your app with shared link, you can activate user's extra features. However, for a small feature it would be unnecessary effort.

Comment: I haven't thought about using a back-end, so thank you for this. And you're right, it won't justify the work I put

Comment: Maybe you can use your own custom share dialog https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494967/10203775

Comment: Take a look into firebase dynamic links. They were used for the now deprecated "Firebase Invites", which was exactly what you describe. Check out the video on Googles site for an overview:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: Thanks guys! Will check